# golang "go get" pulling lot of dependencies. Even trying go get -d ./... fails and says it needs more dependencies

Tags: go

I am trying to write cloud apis for google cloud and just imported 2 packages 
"golang.org/x/net/context"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

When I tried just doing go get it fails saying missing packages. So i tried doing "go get -f ./...". I also tried go getting all what it needs, but the dependencies never end and my src folder is getting loaded with lot of packages. Not sure why it is pulling so much. Please help.

Is something changed in Go 1.12. I was using older versions of Golang before this.
Thank you

go get golang.org/x/...
go get -d ./...

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "golang.org/x/net/context"
  "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
  "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
)
func Test() bool{
    projects := [...]string{
       "xxxx",
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx,compute.ComputeScope)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return true
}
```

The code should compile.

Comment: With the new modules, you shouldn't need to `go get` those. You should be able to simply build your source, and it should pull all the necessary dependencies for you. That said, I'm guessing it is the compute/v1 package that's pulling a lot of other packages.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please elaborate more?

Comment: If I just build it. I get following error. "cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:" (GOROOT and GOPATH)

Comment: There's no reason to use golang.org/x/net/context; it is a transitional package that has been replaced by [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) years ago. Godoc can render the [dependency graph](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1?import-graph&hide=2).

Answer (score 0):

As we talk about Go 1.12 you probably work with `mod`, otherwise, it's a good time to move to it.

So, using mod you need to do the following:
Set `GO111MODULE` environment variable to `"on"`.

```sh
export GO111MODULE=on
```

Then you need to initiate a module

```
go mod init <module_name>
```

The name can include a GitHub path, or be just a name like `go-superlib`, etc.

Then the `mod` will review all your module .go files and create a list of dependencies. You only need to do a

```sh
go get
```

then and `go mod` will do everything for you.

*P.S.: don't try to install `golang.org/x/...` - it's really huge.*

Comment: I tried these steps. "go get" outputted -> 
$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Comment: I dont think it works very well. I ran into multiple issues with this mod thing.  I set GOMOD="" to fix one problem and then it started giving me another set of errors.  Why is this mod so confusing! Please help.  I have started getting another error like package server/api: directory "/xxx/<projectpath>/src/server/api" is not using a known version control system

Comment: "go get" works for me. But now when I build, I get following errors - can't load package: package ./pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go@v0.38.0: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode

Answer (score 0):

I have my project structure as below -

/User/xxxx/projects/projectname where all the project resides. 
The GOPATH is set to /User/xxxx/projects/projectname. 
The Makefile is placed here. 
Then I have one "src" directory and under it, there is 
"server" directory. 
The "server" directory has the Server.go which has "main" in it. 
Under server directory there are other packages. One of the them is "cloud" which has a go file that imports
   "golang.org/x/net/context"
  "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

Now my confusion is, where this go.mod should be and where do i execute go mod from? Even after setting GO111MODULE=on, I get error
go: cannot determine module path for source directory /Users/xxx (outside GOPATH, no import comments)

I could not find a proper documentation yet online. They all talk about create a directory and add a main.go. Import few third party and just build. This does not help.